# jplayer and few interfaces

Tags: jquery, user-interface, swfobject, jplayer

is it possible:

one *jPlayer* instance and 2 interfaces for it, at the same page.

Sample:

[image: sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see (from looking at the source) it seems as though the events (play, pause etc.) are hard-wired to use the identifier of the interface "jp_interface_n":

```
<div id="jp_interface_1" class="jp-interface">
    ....
</div>
```

where n corresponds to the id of the player "jquery_jplayer_n"

```
<div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
```

So in the case above the player "jquery_jplayer_1" would infer an interface id of "jp_interface_1".

I do not think what you are attempting to do is possible without modification of the jplayer component, although I have only looked at it for a couple of minutes so may have missed something.

You have two choices:

1. Ask someone who works on the project via the following Google Group:

   [jPlayer: HTML5 Audio & Video for jQuery](http://groups.google.com/group/jplayer)
2. Create you own interface(s) and wire it up using their api:

   [jPlayer 2.0.0 Developer Guide](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/)